# UIBarButtonItem Offset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to offset the UIBarButtonItems in my app, I need them slightly offset due to the image I use for my navigation bar so it all lines up correctly. I have managed to do this like so:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have two queries though:

1. This stops the buttons have any highlighted state, they function but are no linger visibly pressed down. Anyway around this?
2. More importantly, this works well pushing my buttons upwards in my nav bar, but it pushes them up in my toolbars as well at the bottom of the screen where I need the opposite, actually push them down a little. How can I handle this?

Comment: It will be much easier to understand if you can post an image that what you want . Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out I have found the solution! You can adjust these appearence attributes depending on what view your object is in using the following:

```
appearanceWhenContainedIn:
```

Instead of the standard

```
appearance
```

So I have implemented my needs like so, adjusting up and down depending on if the button is in a nav bar or toolbar:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], nil] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: just saw this now. glad you got it working.  i'm pretty sure my brutish manipulation of frames will work, also.  most apps i've worked on have a single tab bar as the main nav, so the appearance generality is only a nice-to-have.  but i never noticed that appearanceWhenContainedIn: method before.  thanks for the good tip! +1

Comment: Neither did I, super helpful!

Comment: Too bad, can only adjust the vertical space for navigationbar BackButton

Answer (score 3):

The tab bar item frames can be manipulated directly:

```
// get the handle of your tabBar (probably self.tabBarController.tabBar
for (UIView *item in tabBar.items) {
    item.frame = CGRectOffset(item.frame, 0.0, -3.0);
}
```

A less intrusive method for adjusting positions horizontal is to make use of bar button item fixed and flexible spaces:

```
// this will put three pixels between whatever items it sits between
UIBarButtonItem *fixed = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil]
fixed.width = 3.0;
```

Place these into your items array.  So, if you'd like to separate two items by 3px, do this:

```
tabBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1, fixed, button2, nil];
```

Comment: Sorry I think you have misunderstood, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Its not horizontal spacing which is an issue, but vertical. The buttons are normally centred (vertically) on the nav bar but I need to shift the buttons up a little bit and on toolbars, down a little bit.