# Changing only the position of the default backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ipad, alignment, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

So I have a custom nav bar in my iPad app which is a bit larger than the default 44 pixel bar (52 pixels tall).  I want all the items in the nav bar to be center aligned which I have been able to do just fine with the exception of one item, the back button.  I don't want to use a custom back button and instead just use the default one and just nudge its position down a bit so that its aligned with the center of my navbar.  I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this and am not sure if its even possible.  Anybody done something like this?

http://cl.ly/image/0g3f2M260B3C

UPDATE :

This can be done and I found the answer here : [UIBarButtonItem Offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604899/uibarbuttonitem-offset)

Answer (score 1):

Ok well,but we can't change the custom `back` button position so try to implement that one also by custom.

By default back button position was center so we can't change that position.

Comment: actually you can change this and the answer was here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604899/uibarbuttonitem-offset